# How to I restore a Subversion working directory to what is in the repository?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, repository

Ok, I've kind of borked my initial repository. I imported the repository, but got timeout error 80% of the way through, and now trying to finish the import gives me 405 errors and tree conflicts. What I really want to do is just get the files in place. It's a brand new repository, so there's no history to worry about and no user changes to consider. I've tried deleting the files and importing them again, but that just creates conflicts.

So now I just want to scrap the local working copy and revert to whatever exists in the repository, then go through and add in what's missing. Trouble, is, I keep getting tree conflicts.

To possibly compound the problem, I've got a version 1.5 repository and a version 1.6 TortoiseSVN tool. Is that likely to cause problems?

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a v1.5 repository and a v1.6 client will not cause any problems.

The easiest way to revert a working directory to contain what's in the repository is to delete the directory and do a fresh check-out.  The repository doesn't maintain any links to working directories, so you don't have to notify the server when you delete a working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I would scrap the entire repository and just create and new one and start over... Why even bother keeping it when it's empty anyway.

Create a new repository.

Re-import your project.

Answer (score 0):

The version of TortoiseSVN should probably not matter.

What you need to do is delete the repostory on the SVN server and create a new one.